# Bind constraints in Input control of SAPUI5

Tags: data-binding, sapui5, sap-fiori

My rest service expose me a group of fields: each filed has a `value` and a list of attributes: `enabled`, `maxLength` (in case of string), `minLength` (in case of string), `decimals` (number of decimal digits - in case of float).

In OpenUi5 I have:

- `value` and `enabled` are properties of `Input` control [**Link**](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html) (Good!! I can bind properties with model contains the attributes)
- `maxLength` and `decimals` are optionsof [`String` type](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type.String.html)  and [`Float` type](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.type.Float.html)  (**[Link](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.html#constructor)**) but I can't bind options with a model :-/
- `minLength` I can't find a property/option

I would like map (bind) each attribute with component so that automatically the library control for me without writing more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a property called `maxLength` for `Input` Control.

So the only problem I see is binding minLength and decimals for which there is little bit effort is needed.

Solution

- Create your own input control by extending the existing Input
  Control.[How to achieve it?](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f1703b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

Sample Code Structure:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.Input");
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.m.ComplexInput");

sap.m.Input.extend("sap.m.ComplexInput", {
    metadata: {
        properties: {
            minLength: {
                type: "int"
            },
            decimals: {
                type: "int"
            },
            events: {
                //define your own events like checkMinLength,checkDecimals 
            }
        },
        onInit: function () {
            //on init do something
        },
        onAfterRendering: function () {
            //called after instance has been rendered (it's in the DOM)
        },
        _somePrivateMethod: function () {
            /*do someting...*/
        },

        somePublicMethod: function () {
            /*do someting...*/
        },
    }
});

sap.m.ComplexInput.prototype.exit = function () {
        /* release resources that are not released by the SAPUI5 framework */
        //do something
};
```

- Adding CustomData and using wherever you want to. 
  Then you can access custom data in validation process or on liveChange or so..

Bind the other properties to the value of customData

```
var input = new sap.m.Input({
    value: '{value}',
    enabled: '{enabled}',
    maxLength: '{maxLength}',
    customData: [
        new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
        key: 'minLength',
        value: '{minLength}'
        }),
        new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
            key: 'decimals ',
            value: '{decimals}'
        })
    ],
    change: function(oEvent) {
        var src = oEvent.getSource();
        var minLen = src.getCustomData()[0].getValue();
        var decimals = src.getCustomData()[1].getValue();
        if (src.getValue() && src.getValue().length > minLen) {
            src.setValueState('Success');
        } else {
            src.setValueState('Error');
        }
    }
});
```